# Manually convert Object/String a route query param string

Tags: angular, routes

In our Angular app, we are using query params. The params correlate to configuration settings, that can change often. Here's what we're currently using:

```
this.router.navigate([], {
   relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
   queryParams: controlData,
   queryParamsHandling: "merge" // preserve the existing query params in the route
});
```

This doesn't "navigate", BUT it does add to the browser history (if I double click on the browser back arrow, I'll see a long list of all the times I've made minor changes to the query params.

I don't want to add to the history, instead I'd like to use `history.replaceState()`
The only problem is, I need to translate that queryparam object to a route string. If I just try to use `JSON.stringify()`, it won't be correct because there's characters that the route doesn't except.

How can I convert this object of values to a route string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property `replaceUrl` and set it to true in the router.navigate. So you replace the url and don't push a new to the history.

This method will be called by a button click as example.

```js
clickOnButtonAndRouting() {
    let controlData = {hallo: "Hello"};

    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams: controlData,
      queryParamsHandling: "merge", // preserve the existing query params in the route
      replaceUrl: true
    });
```

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was looking for and I don't have to use history.replaceState()! TY!